# Chrome on Android : connection become dead after 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, chat, real-time, long-polling, server-sent-events

We are building a chatroom with our own notification system without depending on GCM but with service worker + SSE.
On desktop it is fine , but on mobile android app (which uses cordova-crosswalk , chromium 53 ) . 
The long running notification connection become stuck after 20-30 minutes and it is in foreground activity. 
It dosen't die with an error , just not reciving data. No error at all which is very weird. No way to reconnect since we do not know if the connection is dead at all.

What would be the cleanest way? Restarting connection every 5 minutes is one idea but it is not clean.
code

```
  runEvtSource(url, fn) {
if (this.get('session.content.isAuthenticated') === true) {
  var evtSource = new EventSource(url, {
    withCredentials: true
  });
}}
```

*Agressive reconnect code*

```
var evtSource = this.runEvtSource(url, fn)
var evtSourceErrorHandler = (event) => {
  var txt;
  switch (event.target.readyState) {
    case EventSource.CONNECTING:
      txt = 'Reconnecting...';
      evtSource.onerror = evtSourceErrorHandler;
      break;
    case EventSource.CLOSED:
      txt = 'Reinitializing...';
      evtSource = this.runEvtSource(url, fn)
      evtSource.onerror = evtSourceErrorHandler;
      break;
  }
  console.log(txt);
evtSource.onerror = evtSourceErrorHandler
```

Comment: Have you tried periodically (less than the timeout you seem to run into) sending data to keep the connection alive?

Comment: nope  i haven't tried that , that means sending fake data ?

Comment: Not "fake" data really, but data which has the sole purpose to keep the connection alive (often referred to as ping/pong).

Comment: When i inspect , the connection is still alive but data just not coming or going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally add a keep-alive layer on top of the the SSE connection. It doesn't happen that often, but sockets can die without dying properly, so your connection just goes quiet and you don't get an error.

So, one way is, inside your get data function:

```
if(timer)clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(reconnect, 30 * 1000);
...process the data
```

In other words, if it is over 30 seconds since you last got data, reconnect. Choose a value based on the frequency of the data you send: if 10% of the time there is a 60 second gap between data events, but never a 120 second gap, then setting the time-out to something higher than 120 seconds makes sense.

You might also want to keep things alive by pushing regular messages from the server to client. This is a good idea if the frequency of messages from the server is very irregular. E.g. I might have the server send the current timestamp every 30 seconds, and use a keep-alive time-out of 45 seconds on the client.

As an aside, if this is a mobile app, bear in mind if the user will appreciate the benefit of reduced latency of receiving chat messages against the downside of reduced battery life.

Comment: When i inspect , the connection is still alive but data just not coming or going.  Is that due to `sockets can die without dying properly` in chromium for mobile android  ? I want to analyze deeply into this. any disconnect event or error event had been reconnected due to agressive reconnection attempt. just the connection that goes silent without error left.

Comment: @PhyoArkarLwin Yes, that is what the problem looks like. E.g. one of the routers between your client and your server has decided to drop the connection (in the case of mobile, perhaps simply because it has been open for a long time), crashed or been restarted.

Comment: Agressive reconnect code updated. For router's decision to disconnect that code fixes - it tries to reconnect whenever network problem occours , i have tested with a specific ISP who disconnnect long running connection may it e websocket or any , after 2-3 minutes.
` in the case of mobile, perhaps simply because it has been open for a long time ` i guess that is the real case

Comment: @PhyoArkarLwin Yes, SSE is supposed to do the restarts for you. But because it is unreliable (I've never measured if it is 90% reliable or 99.99% reliable, the point is that it is not 100%), you still need to implement your own keep-alive logic. It is a shame the SSE standard didn't add a timeout parameter, so it would auto-connect-when-quiet.

Comment: Today i managed to find out what happened:
after 2-3 minutes of background mode (on Xiaomi Max) , the TCP connection to server stop syncing  and answering ACK responses , ending up on "Send-Q" and server side . until it goes back to foreground. 
Then i tried retrying connection , man that got thing worse.
- It fails to nslookup , from the adb-logcat it seemx Xiaomi firewall service prevents it.